SSAS memory usage Object ID Big and Small
I am analyze why my ssas server is consume a lot of memory some times, it is not when we process the cubes.
If I run the DMV memory usage I can set it is OBJECT ID Big and Small that is consume a lot of memory.
I have around 120gb memory on my server and my models are about 6gb together in memory. So 120gb should be enough a lot I think.
The result of running memory usage dmv I got this:

My question is what is the to rows in the top? Big and Small OBJECT ID? that consume a lot of memory.
